# Which pronoun for formal second person plural?

Tags: pronouns, formal

What would be the formal equivalents of:

```
Dove vi siete conosciuti?
Stavo parlando con voi.
```

I read everywhere that `Loro` as plural formal 'you' is restricted only to very formal written work. What would be the spoken equivalent, and which verb conjugation would that pronoun take?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @ToGa!

Comment: To better understand the answer given be sure to get the difference between "loro" as formal of you (the now not common use) and loro as "they"/"them" (what now we use loro for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: it's really uncommon to use `loro` in this case. You may want to use `voi` even in a formal conversation. 
Why? I don't really know. Perhaps, because `voi` was used in the past for the `plurale maestatis`, hence it already contains this formal meaning.

However, even if it's uncommon, you could use loro: 
`Stavo parlando con loro` 
`Dove si sono conosciuti loro?` 
But, believe me, the person to whom you are talking will probably not understand. He'll look around and then ask you "loro chi?" :)

Comment: Yes, it is uncommon, but not unheard of. Occasionally, I still hear some (admittedly, mostly aged) people asking for instance, in front of the exit door of a bus: “Scendono alla prossima?”

Comment: As for the *plurale maiestatis*, it refers to using plural forms for the *first* person: “Con lealtà di Re e con affetto di Padre, Noi veniamo oggi a compiere...”

Comment: but did you read my whole answer? Uncommon means uncommon: rarely used. I've also given an option to translate, but you may end up in the situation where the person does not understand you.

Comment: and this is "plurale maiestatis" from Treccani: "(9) Abbiamo il piacere di comunicarVi che, in questi giorni, abbiamo ricevuto dalla Francia molte recenti opere scientifiche di nuova edizione. Se vorrete passare da noi ci permetteremo di farVi esaminare le opere di medicina, nella speranza che troverete quanto a Voi interessa (Mario A. Santagata, Moderna corrispondenza commerciale italiana, Milano, Hoepli, 1982, p. 239)."

Comment: As for being uncommon, we agree: I was not contradicting you, I was just giving a small, further example.

Comment: As for Treccani's example: in that sentence the plurale maiestatis lies in “abbiamo” and “da noi” (the very article you mention defines p.m. as «l’uso della prima persona del plurale (anziché del singolare)»).

Comment: Se vogliamo, quello non è plurale maiestatis, bensì plurale vero e proprio, perché tu sei l'addetto alla corrispondenza commerciale che ti esprimi per conto di un gruppo.

Comment: comunque, vostra grazia, vostra magnificenza, voi ... sono la logica conseguenza della regola del plurale maiestatis. Se egli usa 'noi' tu risponderai voi in conseguenza della stessa regola.

Comment: si "abbiamo" e "da noi" e' plurale... mentre il "comunicarVi" e' il dare del voi. Quando imparai dattilografia ai tempi di marcocaco il non dare del Voi nella corrispondenza commerciale era pure un erroraccio, incluso non usare la maiuscola che lo avrebbe trasformato in plurale. Il mio testo, anni 80, lo preferiva al Lei. Ora le regole sono sono cambiate parecchio ma l'esempio dal Treccani e' dell'82...

Comment: Spot on Maxadamo. Totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Italian language "voi" means you (plural). The pronoun "loro" means they and is used even as honorific plural form.

However in northern Italy old people used "voi" as honorific form when they talked to their parents.

Comment: Also in Tuscany, especially talking to grandfather and grandmother.